# Getting the filename from a directory only using a string from the filename? and setting that found filename equal to a variable? unix

Tags: unix

Could someone steer me towards a resource to do the following in unix: I want to set a variable equal to a filename so that I can input that variable/filename into a command line tool. I am trying to automate the process of running this command line tool by doing so.
My input files will **always** have the same string at the end their unique names.
How can I get this filename by searching the directory for a string AND successfully input that variable into command line tool?

so the unix code would look something like:

> file1="find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*string*""
>
> my command line tool --input $file1

thanks for your patience!

P.S only one file with that string will be in a directory at a time.

Comment: DO you really need variable? What about `my command line tool --input "*string*"`?

Comment: the string is only part of the filename. it is not the entire files name. my input file names will be different but they will have a short string as part of their name

Comment: Again I do not see a need of variable: `my command line tool --input "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*string*")"`

Comment: thank you for your help!!!! fair enough! I thought it would be cleaner, but this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of work with variables you can directly use the output of `find` command as parameter in your command line:

```
my_command_line_tool --input "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*string*")"
```

If you expect more than one file you may remove the outer quotation marks. But this may broke the command if you have files which match the string, but have special characters like space, new line, etc in filename.